# make user enter a string of integers and output a different string

Tags: c++

hi i am having trouble starting this program as i am new and have no idea how to use loops to construct this thanks

here are the directions:

> For this assignment, write a program named `assignment2` (source is the same name with `.cpp` extension) to
>   prompt the user for an integer value (ignore negative values) and then output this value using the following rules:
>
> - Each digit within the integer value is to be displayed the same number of times as the value of the digit
>     itself, with one exception...the digit 0 will be displayed once, like the digit 1.
> - Separate each string of digits using a single dash character.
>     For example:
>     If the input value is `120473`, the display should look like:
>     `1-22-0-4444-7777777-333`
>     If the input value is `5938061`, the display should look like:
>     `55555-999999999-333-88888888-0-666666-1`
>
> In addition, ask the user if they would like to retry using another integer value. If so, repeat the above. End the
>   program when the user chooses to quit (does not want to retry).
>
> This assignment is an exercise in using the following:
>
> Unary Operators:
>   `!` `++` `--`
>
> Binary Operators:
>   `+` `-` `*` `/` `%` `&&` `||`
>
> Data types:
>   `bool`
>   `char`
>   `int`
>   `enum`
>
> Flow control:
>   `if`-`else`
>   `switch`
>   `do`-`while` loop
>   `while` loop
>   `for` loop
>
> In addition, you are allowed to use any necessary functions provided by the Math library. To include the Math
>   library, add the following line to your list of include statements:
>
> ```
> #include <cmath>
> ```

Comment: So? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Break it down into small pieces and start with reading the user's input because you can't do much until you know you're reading input correctly. Once you have that figured out, split the number up into its individual digits and print out the digits one by one with the dash between them. You can't print out repeated digits until you know you can separate them and you can't prove you've separated them without printing them. Once you have that working, print out the required number of each digit instead of merely one. Implement step by step and test rigorously after each step.

Comment: I have this basic input and output with a switch, thank you for your comment bear with me as i am new to this website and c++.

Comment: Please edit your post with what you have so far and where you are stuck.  What concepts are you having issues with?

Comment: I don't see the need for `bool`, `int`, `enum` types.  Also, don't need `else`, `switch`, nor `while`.  Are these required?  Likewise, no need for `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&&` or `||`.

Comment: my instructor clarified we should use everything specified and i will update with more

Answer (score 0):

For most digit manipulation assignments, I recommend treating the number as a *string* of *characters* rather than as a number.

### The Foundation

Let's start with the foundation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::getline;

int main(void)
{
  cout << "Paused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
  cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above program will hopefully keep the console (terminal) window open until the `Enter` key is pressed.

### Getting The Input

We'll ask the User for a number, this is also known as *prompting*:

```
// The prompt text doesn't change so it's declared as const.
// It's declared as static because there is only one instance.
static const char prompt[] = "Enter a number: ";
cout.write(prompt, sizeof(prompt) - 1U); // Subtract 1 so the terminating nul is not output.

// Input the number as text
string number_as_text;
getline(cin, number_as_text);
```

### Printing The Digits

Really, before this step, you should verify that the text only contains numbers.  Repeat the prompting until the User inputs nothing or valid data.

A string can be accessed as an array.  So we'll set up a loop:

```
const unsigned int length = number_as_text.length();
for (unsigned int index = 0U;
     index < length;
     ++index)
{
  // Extract the digit.
  const char c = number_as_text[index];

  // Verify it is a digit.
  if (!isdigit(c))
  {
    continue;
  }

  unsigned int quantity = c - '0'; // Convert to a number.
  if (quantity == 0) quantity = 1; // The requirements lie, for zero there is a quantity of 1.

  // Use "quantity" to print copies of the character.

}
cout << "\n";
```

### Stuff

I'm not going to write the entire program for you, as you haven't paid for my services.  So you will have to figure out when to print the '-' and how to print many copies of the digit.

If this answer is not correct, please update your question with some clarifications or restrictions.